# Unique filter does not seems to apply on concatenated list

Tags: filter, jinja2, unique

I have two lists that I want to concatenate and then filter for unique values only. I figured this should be possible in Jinja2 using the `unique` filter, but, I'm finding it doesn't work the way I expected. I've used a few different live Jinja parsers to test and they all seem to end up with incorrect output.

For reference, the site I'm using to test my code is https://j2live.ttl255.com/

With an input of data that looks like this:

```yaml
this:
  - one
  - one
that:
  - one
  - two
```

And a template that looks like this:

```
{{ this + that | unique | list }}
```

The rendered output is just the result of concatenating the two lists, when they clearly have duplicate values:

```py
['one', 'one', 'one', 'two']
```

I've tried a bunch of different permutations here and they all end up the same way. Does anyone know how to get this to work as expected? Or am I missing something here? With the intent of the filter, I figured this would work.

I also want to point out, that the expected behaviour does occur when the lists are not concatenated. For example:

```
{{ this | unique | list }}
```

Results in:

```py
['one']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The precedence is taken by the filter over the union of the two list.
What your code is effectively doing is:

```
{{ this + (that | unique | list) }}
```

So, what you really want to do is for the union to happen first, which you can achieve by using parenthesis:

```
{{ (this + that) | unique | list }}
```

Which results in your expected:

```py
['one', 'two']
```

---

This is backed up by this comment on their issue tracker:

> Filters and tests have higher precedence than binary operators. For example `{{ [3] + [2,1] | sort }}` yields `[3, 1, 2]`, not `[1, 2, 3]`.

<sup>*[As commented by ngaya-ll](https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/379#issuecomment-168076202)*</sup>

Comment: Thank you so much! That works perfectly! And I'll keep precedence in mind in the future!